# How do you check if a variable references another declared object in Python?

Tags: python, pointers

Printing type of one variable just returns the pointed data's type

```
i = [5,6,7,8]
j = i
print(type(j))
```

```
<class 'list'>
```

and `j` references a mutable type. So

```
j[0] = 3
print(i)
print(j)
```

```
[3, 6, 7, 8]
[3, 6, 7, 8]
```

I want a function that returns `true` for `j` and `false` for `i`. If it's built-in or anyone could write that it would be appreciated.

Comment: `is_pointer = lambda variable: False`

Comment: @Samathingamajig well stated

Comment: See the answer below, you could `i.__hash__ is None` vs `j.__hash__ is None`, since immutable types are typically hashable, and mutable types typically are not (although there's no real guarantee - you can make either statement false if you really want to, but for practical cases this works)

Comment: "true for j and false for i." *these are the same object*, you can't even in principle write a function that could tell you what you are asking  *and it is the wrong question anyway*

Comment: Variables don't reference variables. They reference _objects_. When you wrote `j = i`, python fully resolved `i` to an anonymous object and then assigned that object to `j`. `j` has no idea that the object happened to come from `i`.

Comment: Why would you need to check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no 'pointers' in Python, like there are in C++ (or similar languages). The only distinction in Python is mutable vs. immutable. But all variables are just references to objects.

Variables with immutable types refer to values that you cannot modify, only replace. `int` is an example of an immutable type.

When you run your code, you assign `5` to `i`, then you assign the value of `i` to `j`, so that `j` now also has the value `5`, but since these are immutable values, you can only change the entire value of either variable, which won't affect the value of the other.

Variables with mutable types have values that you *can* modify. `list` is an example of a mutable type.

When you run this:

```
xs = [1, 2, 3]
ys = xs
xs[0] = 999
```

The last statement modifies the value of both variables, as the list that was the value of `xs` is the same list that was assigned to `ys` and the final instruction modifies that value.

Immutable types including numbers, strings and tuples as well as a few other simple types. Mutable types include lists, dictionaries, and most other more complex classes.

Also, for example have a look at this:

```
a = 1
b = 1
c = b + 1
d = 2
print(id(a), id(b), id(c), id(d))
```

This will print four numbers, but note how the first two numbers will be the same (as they both refer to `1`) and the second two are the same as well (as they both refer to `2`).

Having said all that, if you want to *test* if something is mutable, there's no easy way to do that - but a common reason to want to do so is because you want to test if something is hashable, which you could test:

```
s = 'test'
print(s.__hash__ is None)  # False


xs = [1, 2, 3]
print(xs.__hash__ is None)  # True
```

Comment: Your example with id's really cleared things up for me. Thanks.